# Podcast about archival work and going to another world

Tags: story-identification, podcast

The first season (or maybe first few seasons?) was about archival work, similar to the early seasons of the Magnus Archives. I remember that tapes or files were talked about, and maybe a castle or manor?

The most distinguishing factor is that, after some major story event, the setting shifted drastically to be about an expedition team in an alien world/universe. It was described as massive constructions of metal (or concrete?).

This was most likely between 2010 and 2020.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What was the format, was it fully narrated, or were there multiple performers for different characters?  Was there dialog or was it read like it was mission reports and e-mails?

Comment: @DavidW Multiple performers, dialog. I think the recording was diegetic, first as part of archival work and then as mission logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Archive 81](http://www.archive81.com/). Found by going through several lists of podcasts similar to The Magnus Archives. According to Wikipedia:

> The show follows the story of an audio archivist named Dan, who has
> recently been hired for a job that involves reviewing and cataloguing
> a set of old audio tapes

Comment: You can improve this answer with a link and a summary.